# Button clicks are ignored based on URL

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I've one strange issue.I have one asp.net button on webpage integrate with masterpage.when I call the page using the url something like that **http://www.mywebsite.com** from address bar and click on button nothing is happened,it stays on same url. means it ignore the button click event.

Now if I call the page using url **http://www.mywebsite.com/default.aspx** and click on button then it capture the button click even and execute the code inside that button click

how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Are you sure that `default.aspx` is your default page? And there isn't some other page like `index.htm` that may be taking precedence?

Comment: yes.the default page is default.aspx

Comment: dont know the cause of the issue, but you can go around it by  URL Rewriting: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx